# How to turn off or disable Clipboard Toast Notification in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

How to turn off this notification when copying text?

I tried using [sensitive_clipboard](https://pub.dev/packages/sensitive_clipboard) package but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

As of now there is no solution for this problem. I found this on one of google pixel support page.

> https://support.google.com/pixelphone/thread/181019569/how-can-i-disable-the-new-clipboard-notification-bubble?hl=en

You can add this issue on official android repository.